# Quick Question: Error in Theta Put Option for Black Scholes VBA

Tags: options, black-scholes, vba

I have started an analyst role and I am trying to familiarize myself with the Black-Scholes formula in VBA to gauge option prices.

However, I cannot seem to get the Put Theta to work properly. I have split the complex formula into different parts (not the most elegant solution, but it helps me find the error quicker - I hoped). The Theta Call seems to be working (finallY). You can find this below:

```
Function ThetaCall(S, X, r, t, sig, q)

Dim dOne, dTwo, Nd1, Nd2, TC1, TC2, TC3, TC4, TC5, TC6

    dOne = (Log(S / X) + (r - q + sig ^ 2 / 2) * t) / (sig * Sqr(t))
    dTwo = dOne - sig * Sqr(t)
    Nd1 = Application.NormSDist(dOne)
    Nd2 = Application.NormSDist(dTwo)
    TC1 = S * sig * (Exp(-q * t))
    TC2 = 2 * Sqr(t)
    TC3 = (1 / Sqr(2 * WorksheetFunction.Pi))
    TC4 = (Exp(-dOne ^ 2 / 2))
    TC5 = r * X * (Exp(-r * t)) * Application.NormSDist(dTwo)
    TC6 = q * S * (Exp(-q * t)) * Application.NormSDist(dOne)

    ThetaCall = (((TC1 / TC2) * TC3 * TC4) * -1 - TC5 + TC6) / 365


End Function

Function ThetaPut(S, X, r, t, sig, q)

Dim dOne, dTwo, Nd1, Nd2, TP1, TP2, TP3, TP4, TP5, TP6

    dOne = (Log(S / X) + (r - q + sig ^ 2 / 2) * t) / (sig * Sqr(t))
    dTwo = dOne - sig * Sqr(t)
    Nd1 = Application.NormSDist(dOne)
    Nd2 = Application.NormSDist(dTwo)
    NegNd1 = Application.NormSDist(-dOne)
    NegNd2 = Application.NormSDist(-dTwo)

    TP1 = S * sig * Exp(-q * t)
    TP2 = 2 * Sqr(t)
    TP3 = (1 / Sqr(2 * WorksheetFunction.Pi))
    TP4 = Exp(-dOne * -dOne / 2)
    TP5 = r * X * Exp(-r * t) * NegNd2
    TP6 = q * S * Exp(-q * t) * NegNd1

    ThetaPut = (((TP1 / TP2) * TP3 * TP4) * -1 + TP5 - TP6) / 365

End Function
```

Could any of you experts help me find the Theta Put error? Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Comment: I believe you have a problem in TP4 , you need the exponential of a negative square halved, you have the sign positive. TP4 should be Exp(-(-dOne * -dOne) / 2). Of course you can simplify that to leave a single  '-' sign.

Comment: Thank you so much. That solves indeed the problem, noob2. All is working now. Much appreciated!